# Function that is allowed in C++ is not allowed in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, inheritance, compiler-errors, polymorphism

In C++, we can do this(pseudo-code):

```
class A {
    public:
    virtual void a(A a)=0;
    }

class B : A {
    public:
    virtual void a(B b);
}
```

But when I write the equivalent in C#:

```
public abstract class A
{
public virtual void a(A a){}
}

public class B : A
{
public override void a(B b){}
}
```

the compiler gives an error that says B.a doesn't override A.a. Why doesn't C# allow this? It is very resonable to allow this practise because it obeys the principles of polymorphism.

Comment: Can you give a C# code example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in the code.

Comment: I think that a better C# equivalent would have class 'A' be an interface, not an abstract class - this should give you the behavior you want.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Making `A` an interface won't affect the error at all.

Comment: @sepp2k: It works in my test - make 'A' an interface, then 'B' implements 'A'.  This offers the behavior mentioned by VictorPrograss - an 'A' reference that points to a 'B' calls the method defined in 'B'.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Could you post your test code somewhere, so I can take a look at it?

Comment: @sepp2k: I was wrong - you're right - an interface isn't the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ version of the code doesn't override the method either. But because C++ doesn't have an `override` keyword¹, you don't get an error for that because the compiler doesn't know you meant to override the method.

If you want the same behavior in C# as you get in C++, you can just remove the `override` keyword and replace it with `new`.

¹ It does in C++11, but I'm assuming you didn't use that or else you would have gotten an error.

> It is very resonable to allow this practise because it obeys the principles of polymorphism.

No, it doesn't. Consider this:

```
A a = new B();
a.a(new A());
```

If `B.a` overrode `A.a`, the above code would call `B.a` with the argument `new A()`. But `B.b` takes an argument of type `B`, so that would not work.

Comment: C++11 added a *contextual keyword* `override` that will flag that as an error.

Comment: If I use the new keyword, and then define a A reference that points to a B, and then call method a, would I call the a method of B?

Comment: @VictorPrograss As Servy said, no, you wouldn't. But note that the same is true in your C++ program.